# What is the snow level going to be in the Atlassian mountains(Toubkal) in the end of April?

Tags: weather, snow, mountains, morocco

The question is should we prepare to snow hiking in the end of April going to [Toubkal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toubkal)?

How can we predict or make educated guess on snow level?
Is there any resource we can monitor snow level in the Atlassian mountains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snow levels should be reduced by the end of April, but expect snow at the higher elevations (which continue receiving new snow often through May). If moisture blows in off the Atlantic, conditions can change extremely rapidly, so be sure to check the weather forecast before ascending. When I was there late last March, the weather was lovely in Imlil one afternoon, and we had a foot of snow in just a few hours the next morning.

You can see the general weather trends for Jebel Toubkal here: https://www.responsiblevacation.com/vacations/mount-toubkal/travel-guide/best-time-to-trek-mount-toubkal

Detailed forecasts are at: https://www.mountain-forecast.com/peaks/Toubkal/forecasts/4167

But, once again, beware of the possibility of extremely rapid changes. With a little prudence, you should have a great time. It's a stunningly beautiful place.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have any sources for past snow levels? A good educated guess is always to take the average snow level at this time slightly corrected if the current snow level differs strongly from the long term average